# Why is my cookie not being echoed into the html textbox?

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have a page that executes a script after some user input. The script calculates distance and a cost. I then turn the cost into a cookie to be transferred and displayed in a form on another page. After the script is ran and the redirect happens I get no display of my cookie on the form page. Not sure what is happenning.

Form snippet:

```
<div class="col-md-10" style="margin-top:12px;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-Default" class="col-md-4 control-label" style="text-align:right;">Job Pay<span style="color:red;">*</span> :</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name="jobpay" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE[$cost]; ?>"/>
                    <em class="error slotsError" style="color:red;"></em>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script snippet:

```
$start = $_POST["origin"];
$end = $_POST["destination"];


$value = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '+', $start));

$value2 = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '+', $end));

$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins= 
{$value}&destinations={$value2}&mode=driving&language=English-
en&key=$key";
$json = file_get_contents($url); // get the data from Google Maps API
$result = json_decode($json, true); // convert it from JSON to php array
$result2 = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];

$value3 = strtolower(str_replace(',', '', $result2));
$value4 = strtolower(str_replace('km', '', $value3));
$value5 = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $value4));

$pay = "0";

if($value5 <="10") {
    $pay = "10";

}
elseif($value5 >= "10" && $value5 <= "15") {
    $pay = "15";

}
else {
$far="too far";

}

$cost = "payamount";
$cost_value = $pay;
setcookie($cost, $cost_value, time() + (86400), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

Comment: i think it should be inside qoutes like $_COOKIE['$cost']

Comment: @Taha Dhailey unfortunately that is not working

Comment: Use <?php echo $_COOKIE["payamount"]; ?>

Comment: @Guarav Rai I have and still nothing

Comment: $_COOKIE['cost'] did u remove $ from cost??

Comment: @Taha Dhailey yes all of that was attempted. I have found the solution and posted below

Answer (score 1):

So the reason was I was not specifying a subdomain as well. The correct format is:

```
setcookie($cost, $cost_value, time() + (86400), "/", "subdomain.com");
```